# Mouse not being dealt with correctly, what should I do?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, mouse

Deus Ex: Human Revolution is not working correctly with my mouse. I have an extra monitor, off to the left.

When I play the game, the mouse is not 'grabbed', so if I look to the left, I'll see the mouse pointer come out into my second monitor (the view still changes as the mouse moves around the second screen). If I then click, the game loses focus and minimizes.

If I'm hacking, I can't actually click `Hack`, as there's a weird offset applied to the mouse. If do I click `Hack`, number 4 is activated. I can't move the cursor right enough to click `Hack`.

I can disconnect the monitor, then it works, but I'd rather not do that. Is there a setting somewhere I need to change?

Comment: related: [Mouse moving out of the Game with dual screen](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6308/mouse-moving-out-of-the-game-with-dual-screen)

Comment: @Tobias That looks good, it seems to sort out half the problem at least!

Comment: give it a shot, maybe this also fixes the offset problem... I guess DeusEx converts your mouse x-position by a ratio of (width #1) / (width #1 + #2) (or inverse) so if it doesn't work and there's no patch you'd somehow need to convince it there is no spoon. no wait, no second monitor I mean... Alternatively, did you try different resolutions or windowed mode?

Comment: I play on 2 screens and have no problem. Try playing on your primary monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this just by restarting my computer, I think it might have been due to the following sequence of events:

1. Playing Deus Ex
2. Hibernating the computer
3. Starting up the computer again, and attaching the screen
4. Playing Deus Ex again